# MYSQL Sum field values of a row while grouping by a different row

Tags: mysql, sum

I needed a little boost so any helping hand is appreciated.
Here is a sample table:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------
|Order # |   Name    |    product   |    Quantity    |
 ----------------------------------------------------
| 15     |   John    |   Scooter    |        1       |
 ----------------------------------------------------
| 15     |   John    |   Scooter    |        1       |
 ---------------------------------------------------- 
| 15     |   John    |   Bicycle    |        1       |
 ---------------------------------------------------- 
| 16     |   Jane    |   Wheel      |        1       |
 ---------------------------------------------------- 
| 16     |   Jane    |   Pedal      |        1       |
 ---------------------------------------------------- 
| 16     |   Jane    |   Pedal      |        1       |
 ---------------------------------------------------- 
| 17     |   Mike    |   Scooter    |        1       |
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

The output I m looking for is:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------- 
| 15     |   John    |   Scooter    |        2       |
 ---------------------------------------------------- 
| 15     |   John    |   Bicycle    |        1       |
 ---------------------------------------------------- 
| 16     |   Jane    |   Wheel      |        1       |
 ---------------------------------------------------- 
| 16     |   Jane    |   Pedal      |        2       |
 ---------------------------------------------------- 
| 17     |   Mike    |   Scooter    |        1       |
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

How do I go about this in MYSQL?

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses!

Comment: what is wrong in my answer?

Comment: @Sadikhasan: your answer groups all product values into one result.  For instance it shows 15:John:Scooter:3 which is not the intended result :) thank you for your help

Comment: sorry! i forgot group by name now check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select `Order`, Name, product, sum(Quantity) as total
from tablename
group by
product,name
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
select `order #`,name,product,sum(quantity) from your_table group by `order #`,name,product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  `Order #`, Name, product, sum(Quantity) total
from 
  table_name
group by
  1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Order,Name,product,sum(Quantity) as Quantity  
FROM table_name GROUP BY product,name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `group by`

```
   Select `order #`, name, product, sum(quantity)
   from table_name
   group by `order #`, name, product
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e92dd7/1)